# How can I query cosmosdb/sql where two properties change over time

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a database that has documents with a Version property and Tier property

example:

```
{
    partitionKey: "AEDlCE4k4Xl/hv6o7ZNtSX9B5XjtfOKxYDCgGbQB518=",
    id: "1055984d-01bd-4fbf-877f-0c18ce91552e",
    Version: 1,
    Tier: "basic"
},
{
    partitionKey: "ABClCE4k4Xl/hv6o6ZNtSX9B5XjtfOKxYDCgGbQB424=",
    id: "1055984d-01bd-4fbf-877f-0c18ce91552e",
    Version: 2,
    Tier: "standard"
}
```

I want to be able to query my documents to find which ids have a Version=1 and Tier=basic and also have a Version=2 and Tier=standard.

I've tried to write a query like this:

```
select c.id from c
where (c.Version = 1 and c.TierId = "basic")
AND (c.Version = 2 and c.TierId = "standard")
```

I don't get any results back though. I think it's looking for a specific doc that has both version 1 and version 2. Is there a way I can update my query where it doesn't use the `AND`?

EDIT: I wanted to also mention that I have a separate partitionkey that is not the id. Updated my example docs above

Comment: I'm not super familiar with cosmos, but you do have JOIN or IN (sub-query) options, so something like this should achieve your desired result ....  SELECT c1.id FROM c AS c1 WHERE c1.Version = 1 AND c1.TierId = "basic" AND c1.id IN (SELECT c2.id FROM c AS c2 WHERE c2.Version = 2 AND c2.TierId = "standard")

Comment: And similarly, without me knowing completely your database structure, because those 2 sets of data are essentially separate records, from the point-of-view of the database, you can never has a single record that has both 1 AND 2 as the "Version" value ..... the fact is, you have two separate records that share the same "id" value, but have different "Version" and "Tier" values

Comment: @Craig yeah, I see what you're saying. Since I have two separate records, I dont think I can do a join on the same table. I may have to get the results for Version 1 and Version 2 separately and then combine them outside the db

Comment: You should certainly be able to JOIN on the same table, or try the query in my previous comment which is a simpler way to get the relevant IDs that match your criteria.  Of course, if you want to include additional fields, or also get data from other tables, then you'll need a JOIN.  Something like SELECT * FROM c AS c1 JOIN c AS c2 ON c2.id = c1.id AND c2.Version = 2 AND c2.TierId = "standard" JOIN ... (other tables, if needed) WHERE c1.Version = 1 AND c1.TierId = "basic"

Comment: FYI comments are not for extended discussion. Also, it's very difficult to read code (or in this case queries) as unformatted text within a comment.

Comment: @Craig - `Join` in CosmosDb core API is [within a single document](https://cosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnet/labs/03-querying_in_azure_cosmosdb.html#join-within-your-documents). Not even across documents in the same collection and certainly not across collections (not tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below gets kind of close (If `Condition1Met` and `Condition2Met` are both `1` then documents meeting both of the conditions were present for an `id`)

```
SELECT c.id, 
       MAX(c.Version = 1 AND c.Tier = "basic" ? 1 : 0) AS Condition1Met, 
       MAX(c.Version = 2 AND c.Tier = "standard" ? 1 : 0) AS Condition2Met
FROM c
where (c.Version = 1 AND c.Tier = "basic")
OR (c.Version = 2 AND c.Tier = "standard")
GROUP BY c.id
```

But in practice unless the collection and result set are small this is unlikely to be suitable as ["You can't use continuation tokens for queries with GROUP BY"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/pagination#continuation-tokens).

(maybe you could use a home made keyset pagination approach though and tack on an `ORDER BY c.id` and add a condition to the `WHERE` that the next batch should be `>` than the highest seen in the previous batch)

I think the best options are.

1. Write a query with the `WHERE` clause with all `OR`-ed conditions, ordered by `id`, and projecting the `id`, `Version`, and `Tier` properties. And have client code process this and keep track whilst iterating through this for each `id` seen which condition(s) they matched - and use this to find the `id` matching **both** conditions.
2. See if you are in a position to use the [analytical store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/analytical-store-introduction) for this collection. You can then write pretty much any type of cross document query against that. (Most likely current blockers to this would probably be if you use continuous backup or if the latency of the synch to this was not acceptable)

Comment: I opted for option 1 where I am running the query right now using the group by clause and then doing some post-processing to see which values satisfy Condition1Met and Condition2Met. My db is somewhat small right now (20k documents) but will probably look into option 2 as the long term solution as the db grows

Comment: @DannyD - yeah my concern for the single `group by` without any `where docid > x` and `order by` is that it might just give you partial results with no way of really seeing this or continuing on. Because it won't return infinite documents or spend infinite RU on it so at some point it will cut off. At least with the `ORDER BY` you have a point to continue from and see if there is anything else remaining after that value

Answer (score 0):

First, note that you cannot have duplicate `id` values, as every document must have a unique `id` (the exception being when the same `id` is used in different partitions, meaning you have a partition key other than `/id`). So the sample data you gave above isn't really valid. You'd need a different guid for each.

Now for the query. You've created an impossible situation, where a document has two different sets of values. Rather than using `AND`, combine your checks with `OR`. Something like:

```sql
SELECT c.id FROM c
where (c.Version = 1 AND c.TierId = "basic")
OR (c.Version = 2 AND c.TierId = "standard")
```

This will result in a set of `id` for documents that meet either of the conditions.